# Django WSGIRequest.get_full_path() doesn't return the full URI

Tags: python, django, azure

I have wrote a piece of Django code to get "tweets" from a website like "twitter" called weibo in China.(Indeed the problem is nothing related to this task). This piece of code run properly in my local computer Django test web server(started by the command: `python manage.py runserver`).

The code piece likes these:

```
def authsucc(request):
    APP_KEY = '5032*****'
    APP_SECRET = '367362***************'
    CALLBACK_URL = 'http://lifein.azurewebsites.net/weibo/authsucc.html'

    client = APIClient(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET,  redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL)
    r = client.request_access_token(request.build_absolute_uri()[-32:])
    #return HttpResponse(request.get_full_path())

    access_token = r.access_token
    expires_in = r.expires_in
    client.set_access_token(access_token, expires_in)
    r = client.statuses.user_timeline.get()
    resp = ""
    for st in r.statuses:
        resp += st.text + "<br/>"

    return HttpResponse(resp)
```

But the problem is after I deploy the website on my Windows Azure website(Host on an IIS 8.0 webserver). The function call `request.get_full_path()` didn't work and just return "weibo/authsucc.html" while the actual request is "http://lifein.azurewebsites.net/weibo/authsucc.html?code=08e69b6acb825029f4fa5af1f7ed394d" I checked the local var in Django's debug mode. Parts of it:

```
request 
"<WSGIRequest\npath:/weibo/authsucc.html,\n
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,\n
POST:<QueryDict: >{}>,\n 
'HTTP_HOST': 'lifein.azurewebsites.net',\n
'HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL': '/weibo/authsucc.html?code=08e69b6acb825029f4fa5af1f7ed394d',\n
'IIS_UrlRewriteModule': '7.1.0761.0',\n 
'IIS_WasUrlRewritten': '1',\n
'PATH_INFO': u'/weibo/authsucc.html',\n
'PATH_TRANSLATED':'C:\\\\DWASFiles\\\\Sites\\\\LifeIn\\\\VirtualDirectory0\\\\site\\\\wwwroot\\\\handler.fcgi\\\\weibo\\\\authsucc.html',\n 
'QUERY_STRING': '',\n 
'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',\n 
'REQUEST_URI': '/weibo/authsucc.html?code=08e69b6acb825029f4fa5af1f7ed394d',\n                     'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.0',\n 
'UNENCODED_URL': '/weibo/authsucc.html?code=08e69b6acb825029f4fa5af1f7ed394d',\n 
'URL': '/handler.fcgi',\n 
'wsgi.errors': <cStringIO.StringO object at 0x010392A0>,\n 
'wsgi.input': <cStringIO.StringI object at 0x012C9458>,\n 
'wsgi.multiprocess': True,\n 
'wsgi.multithread': False,\n 
'wsgi.run_once': False,\n 
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',\n 
'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>"
```

We can see that the 'REQUEST_URI' and 'HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL' attribute of the request are correctly set, however the GET QueryDict are empty. The `request.get_full_path()` returns "/weibo/authsucc.html" instead of excepted "/weibo/authsucc.html?code=08e69b6acb825029f4fa5af1f7ed394d" in local server. I wonder how to solve this problem. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

The querystring is not part of the path of an uri. So the behavior that is observed is correct. That creates a new question, how to get the full uri from a django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest a object. The logical answers seems to be:

```
uri = '%s?%s' % (request.get_full_path, request.QUERY_STRING)
```

Though this is creates as reconstruction it will not give you the exact uri that was used to perform the http request. For example, there is no way to distinguish /path/ from /path/? .

To determine this for sure it's required to gain direct access to the raw http request. I have not yet been able to do this. I will update when I find a working answer.

Comment: It probably depends on the version, but request.get_full_path() has the query parameters in it according to the docs as far back as 1.6 (whose docs are archived)